# Bound service crash with "Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()" error

Tags: android, service, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo

I'm currently working on audio playback app and I'm using a started bound service to play music in background. I start and bind to the service using following code.

```
val intent = Intent(context, MusicService::class.java)
context.startService(intent)
context.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, 0)
```

It gets promoted to foreground when playing and gets demoted when music is paused.

```
// onAudioPlay
service.startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, notification)

// onAudioPause
service.stopForeground(false)
```

Service work fine up to now. But when the notification is swiped(removed) by the user in the paused state, the service crashes after few seconds giving this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myplayer, PID: 4380
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
        android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1775)
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This only happens on Oreo and I already read about the background limitations in Oreo. But following points bugs me.

- This service is a bound service(which aren't affected by limitations)
- I never use Context.startForegroundService() to start the service.(and don't want to use it)
- The service doesn't crash when it gets demoted from foreground, it's happens when removing the notification.

Why is the service is crashing? What am I doing wrong? I'm very thankful if someone tell me whats happening here.

Comment: This is interesting. I suggest you post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted instead of editing the question. It is more clear to the future reader as well.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Thanks for the suggestion. I added an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To expand on [UdeshUk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326769/1299562) - any use of `MediaButtonReceiver` (either building pending intents or just receiving media button intents) can result in your service being called with `startForegroundService`, because `MediaButtonReceiver.onReceive` starts your service in that way on Oreo.  I haven't seen this documented anywhere.

Comment: I have the same issue calling MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent, and there is a note in the docs "Once the service is started, it must start to run in the foreground". It was quite cryptic until reading your answer.

Comment: If you register a MediaButtonReceiver in your manifest Android can try and restart your media session by calling startForegroundService, and if you don't show a notification soon enough in this case it will cause the ANR. You can opt out of this behavior as described in the [docs]
(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#restarting-inactive-mediasessions)

Comment: Do you know if using `setMediaButtonReceiver(null)` will cause any issues with using external media controls?  I updated my code to use this and it still recognizes button commands from my Bluetooth headset but it seems odd to just set it to null.

Comment: @RJAylward But it is actual only for Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher?

Answer (score 10):

I found the problem. In my notification I have set

```
setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(service, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))
```

So when user removes the notification it calls startForegroundService() because I called stopForeground() previously when pausing.

To overcome, I used a custom pending intent and handled it in the `onStartCommand()` instead of **MediaButtonReveiver's** PendingIntent

Comment: Can you explain how that line of code calls startForegroundService() implicitly? I have similar problem where I never call it and it might provide clues. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveM the above line creates a `PendingIntent` which targets the `MediaButtonReceiver`, which then may call your service with `startForegroundService` (which also depends on how you configured your intent filters in the manifest). So the best solution to avoid those `startForegroundService`-calls is to avoid the `MediaButtonReveiver`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629196/1394330

Comment: @UdeshUK I'm confused when you said you created a custom pending intent.  Wouldn't just adding a notification to `onStartCommand()` in your `MediaBrowserService` work?

Comment: @KrisB Sorry I don't use a ```MediaBrowserService```. I have a custom music service to handle playback and handle media files.

Answer (score 7):

**You must call this method inside your Service class onCreate() method:->**

```
private void startServiceOreoCondition(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {


            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_service";
            String CHANNEL_NAME = "My Background Service";

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    CHANNEL_NAME,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tgc_icon).setPriority(PRIORITY_MIN).build();

            startForeground(101, notification);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but as was mentioned before, it's the `MediaButtonReceiver`; it has this code:

```java
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
        startForegroundService(context, intent);
        ...
    }
```

I'm using the receiver in a bound service, so I created a class that has the exact same code as `MediaButtonReceiver`, except for this line. I replaced it with:

```java
        context.startService(intent);
```

Comment: Really nice of Google to make us aware of this.  What happens if Google ever modifies the code in `MediaButtonReceiver`?  Do you have copy the code into your project everytime there are any changes to it?

Comment: I guess so, I guess they did that as some kind of enforcement; you can only access the media button in foreground. That was shortsighted though, the entire services api is a pain any way.

Comment: I just set `setMediaButtonReceiver` to `null` and that seemed to work as mentioned here:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#restarting-inactive-mediasessions

I was worried it would effect handling media controls from a Bluetooth headset but it doesn't.

Comment: Are you still able to listen to media button's events?

Comment: @KrisB But it is actual only for Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs [8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)

> The system allows apps to call Context.startForegroundService() even
>   while the app is in the background. However, the app must call that
>   service's startForeground() method within five seconds after the
>   service is created.

So, you have to call startForeground inside onCreate() for your service.

Comment: Yeah. But this happen while my activity is open. So my app isn't in the background. And also I don't start the service with startForegroundService().

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem but i fixed it using notification service

```
public void createNotificationChannel(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel serviceChanel =new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Forground service Chane"
                , NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChanel);
    }
}
```

create Chanel id in begin of class

`public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";`

and service  onStartCommand indside

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {


        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("ForgroundService")
                .setContentText("Any message")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1,notification);
    }
```

put that code

Sourse https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/

Answer (score 0):

`MediaButtonReceiver` invoke startForegroundService and it is a culprit for me. My problem occured when I had no media to play (the playlist was empty). I solved that by showing notification and cancelling it right away in `onStartCommand`:

```
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
        startForeground(99, builder.build());
        stopForeground(true);
        
        MyMediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSessionCompat, intent);
    
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
      }
```